# Bibliography style with author, and without date

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I would like to use a bibliographic style such that as the amsalpha has abbreviation for authors. But, unlike amsaplha, has no date. I hope that the attached image describes my problem. I prefer the first line in the picture which has no date in brackets. I do not know if it makes a difference or not, but I use a bib file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged the question with `biblatex` tag.

With `biblatex` this is as easy as giving a suitable definition in `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`. The original definition, which includes the year, can be found in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 1406-1416 in v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1406-L1416). All we need to do is drop the year.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [SR; Wor; Gee; Nus]]

---

If you want to or need to use BibTeX a solution will involve modifying a copy of the `.bst` file (`\bibliographystyle`) you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do not apply your idea yet, but it seems so interesting to me.